# Is it possible to filter Google Play search results by permission?

Tags: google-play-store, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search the Play Store by permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20619/how-to-search-the-play-store-by-permissions)

I would like to exclude apps that require permissions I find too intrusive from Google Play search results like network access, reading SMS, location, etc.

Is it possible to filter search results by permission on Google Play website and Android app? Or maybe from other sites like Appbrain?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the same thing discussed in [How to search the Play Store by permissions?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20619), correct?

Comment: @eldarerathis You are right. It seems ["filter permission" request](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=filter+permission) _filtered_ this question ;) Thanks