# How to search Google Play and Huawei Store for applications coming with ADB supported public API?

Tags: adb, android-emulator, emulators

re.:
How to search Google Play and Huawei Store for applications coming with ADB supported public API ?

I am interested to implement Software Interoperability Act into force and practice
and ask developers to offer API versions of their applications to be offered via Google Play Store, Huawei Store as an extra option (fee/no fee).

I am aware, it may take some time due summer holiday time but learn today, which one comes with API as add-on and how to search for API enabled Android applications for basic tests via ADB.

I would like to know, which applications can output results, actions, data via USB ADB link and what data formats are offered for postprocessing and scripting.

I would like to build directory of API enabled Android applications with full step-by-step manual on how to start, what input data are accepted and what output can be generated.

Since it may not be smart to install applications for testing,. one after the another to smartphone, I am looking for smartphone's emulator which can be run remotely via Internet, supporting USB ADB emulation via www JS scripting, coming with working API scripts for individual applications.

I would like to know state-of-the-art within the above to let me assess my efforts and time to be consumed, the above project to ccome true if not already offered or supported by third parties./

thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search the Play Store by permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20619/how-to-search-the-play-store-by-permissions)

Comment: Also realize that `adb` is a developer tool, so geared toward app developer workflow. Individual apps unless written, do not interoperate as mobile devices contains lots of personal data and increasingly in a [sandbox](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips) due to bad/malicious actors. Getting developers to use any particular API is off-topic (and akin to herding cats) unless you are the platform owner like Google or can financially pay people to support any third-party API.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thank you for your kind comments and answers

" Individual apps unless written, do not interoperate 
exactly, but may interoperate and how to call this feature by default to let developers to expose it to users ?
Not sure how to learn ADB API support from permissions
__
https://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=search
Search apps by category and permission

__
https://play.gqqnbig.me/
Google Play Advanced Search

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro

Comment: @MorrisonChang
example of the preferred use of ADB API:
heart rate + oxygen saturation app getting data from sensors installed in smartwatch.
Live chart is generated but I need to add datalogger functionality via ADB API, studying AndroidManifest.xml file for offered Intents  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro - 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters -
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

Comment: What data can be received by an app is noted in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. The only way I know to get the manifest is to download the app. What data an app provides is defined by it's "Content Providers". An indicator for a content providers are special custom permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @MorrisonChang ok, I need to start with https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters
Intent to sendBroadcast() or sendOrderedBroadcast()
since "A broadcast is a message that any app can receive. 
"Implicit intents do not name a specific component, but instead declare a general action to perform, which allows a component from another app to handle it. For example, if you want to show the user a location on a map, you can use an implicit intent to request that another capable app show a specified location on a map.

Comment: @Robert thank you, is it possible for a developer to publish direct download link to AndroidManifest.xml file via Google Store to let a user to get prior knowledge on what intents are supported and what broadcast can be processed via USB ADB to receive data output redirected to USB interface ?
Example: to study quality of Audio2MIDI conversion I would like to live overlay on display: MIDI, raw FFT data and Equilizer app chart.
Ok, I can run 3 applications individually on 3 smartphones and have camera to record images from 3 displays to generate live conversion quality analysis

Comment: Search by permissions, offered by https://play.gqqnbig.me/search?q=ADB%20API&ap=false&ad=false

Google Play Advanced Search

is down

Taking too long to load result. Something might be wrong.